# What type of bearing should I use to allow a ring to rotate around a fixed axle

Tags: bearings, friction

What type of bearing should I use to allow a ring to rotate around a fixed axle. Axle is horizontal.

The rings inner diameter can be flush with the stationary rod or have a gap as needed. What type of bearing (or other device) would I use to allow the ring to spin freely?

I know I can get a basic bearing and maybe solder the ring onto the bearing but I want something more professional and elegant. Does there exist a two piece bearing set that you insert from either side of the rings inner diameter and connects together, and then can be slid onto the axle?

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of what you need? How big? What forces or rotation speed does this need to take? What’s your budget?

Comment: What do you think of as a "basic bearing" -- a journal bearing, oilite bronze, ball bearing?